# Add ids as array in a session and return products according to ids inside it

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to add multiple products to a session, and then at a quote page display all the products in that session.

How I'm doing it:

Link to quote page which sends the productid with it:

```
<p><a class="offertelink" href="offerte.php?product='.$productcr[0]['id'].'">Request a quote</a></p>
```

Then on the quote page I put it in a session:

```
$_SESSION['product'] = $_GET['product'];
```

But this only remembers one product, what if I go back to add another product, then only that new product is displayed instead of both products that I added.

I want to save all id's in a session and then inside a query display all the saved products by using  `id IN ('1', '2', '3')`

With the id's being the productids that are send by clicking the link.

I tried a couple of things like turning the session into an array but still it only remembers one product id. I have session_start at the top of a file I include everywhere.

```
$_SESSION['product'] = array();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check if `$_SESSION['product']` already exist. If not create it as an `ARRAY`. Then add all subsequent IDs to the `$_SESSION['product']` Array like this: `$_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];`. That way, you are sure to have an array of IDs when ever you try to access `$_SESSION['product']`

```
<?php //<==  NOTICE THAT THERE IS NO WHITE SPACE BEFORE "<?php"

    // FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT.
    // DO THIS AT THE VERY TOP OF EACH SCRIPT THAT NEEDS ACCESS TO $_SESSION DATA
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }

    // DO THIS ON THE PAGE WHERE YOU ARE SETTING THE IDs INTO THE $_SESSION
    if( !isset($_SESSION['product'])){
        $_SESSION['product'] = array();
    }

    $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
```

**UPDATE: Get the String Value for use in Database**

```
<?php

    if( !isset($_SESSION['product'])){
        $_SESSION['product'] = array();
    }

    // CHECK FIRST THAT $_GET['product'] IS SET BEFORE ADDING IT TO SESSION
    if( isset($_GET['product']) ){
        $_SESSION['product'][] = $_GET['product'];
    }

    // IN THE FILE THAT USES THE DATA FOR DATABASE TRANSACTIONS,
    // YOU CAN DO THIS:
   // THE $valuesForDB WOULD CONTAIN SOMETHING LIKE: '2','7','10','12','13'
    $valuesForDB    = "'" .  implode("','", $_SESSION['product']) . "'";


    var_dump($valuesForDB);  //<== PRODUCES::: string ''2','7','10','12','13'' (length=22) [FOR EXAMPLE]

    var_dump($_SESSION['product']);
    // PRODUCES SOMETHING LIKE:::
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 7
      2 => int 10
      3 => int 12
      4 => int 13
```

Comment: Alright, but this still only saves one product. When I print the array it only shows 1 id, while i added one, went back and added another one.

Comment: I get the following error with that code: `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in`

Comment: Added the top code to my connection file under session_start which is included everywhere. And the bottom code only at the quote page.

Comment: @twan    So; at which point did you get the Error? Remember that `$_SESSION['product']` **is an Array** so you just can't access it like a String. See the Updated Section of the Post for more...

Comment: when I refresh the quote page it just shows the fatal error. At line 8 which is the line with the extra brackets, this is where I get the fatal error: `$_SESSION['product'][]`

Comment: It also just keeps 1 value. When I add another product it only shows the id of that product, not the one I added before.

Comment: It still sees the session as a string, so I added `$_SESSION['product'] = array();` above the if statement, and the error is gone. But still I can only add 1 id.